# How to use the degree symbol in programming listing?

Tags: listings, lyx

I'm using lyx and get the error message, that the ° symbol got excluded, when I'm trying the following example:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{lstlisting}
10°C
\end{lstlisting}
```

EDIT: as asked, here the latex code from lyx, where it is needed:

```
%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/verbatimfiles}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listing}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \emph{class variables}\\
\emph{}
\begin{lstlisting}
Public celsius() As Char = {" ", "°", "C", "/", "m", "i", "n"}
\end{lstlisting}
This variable is used to trim the output of Linkam functions, so numerical
value operation\emph{ }are possible with the outputs. It is made public,
so it can be accessed by functions outside this class, where the trimming
is nescessary.\\

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To be completely honest, it is programming code, write *10 deg. celsius* or something similar.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: For one thing, you should have a line break after `\begin{lstlisting}`; otherwise, you'll get a compile error. Also, could you include the exact error you're getting from LyX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `${^\circ}$`? This would give you the degree sign, when option `mathescape` is enabled.

And your script would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
10${^\circ}$C
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that give `10${^\circ}$C` since it is a verbatim environment?

Comment: Jup.. True, not as easy as I thought..

Comment: after changing the encoding to UTF-8 this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the problem arises because of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.
Unicode characters are only supported, when there is a font encoding, which contains the character. Otherwise package `inputenc` would not know, how to print the character. The encoding `TS1` can be used, which is loaded by package `textcomp`.

The next obstacle is that ackage `listings` does not support multi-byte characters.

There are some workarounds:

## Option `mathescape`

Package `listings` provides escape mechanisms, one of them is `mathescape`, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253351/16967) of Anne. The math stuff is not
parsed and split by the `listings` parser.
Macro `\text` of package `amstext` (or `amsmath`) escapes back to text mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}% TS1 encoding for the degree sign
\usepackage{amstext}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
10$\text{°}$C
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This version is useful for flexible column layouts.

> [image: Result]

## Option `literate`

The `literate` feature replaces tokens (UTF-8 byte sequence for the degree sign) with the correct symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}% TS1 encoding for the degree sign
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[literate={°}{\textdegree}1]
10°C
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Useful for fixed column layouts, the `1` says that the replacement takes the place of one character.

> [image: Result literate]

## Package `listingsutf8`

If the characters of this listings fit into a known 8-bit encoding, then
package `listingsutf8` helps, which reencodes a file on read for `\listinputlisting`. Environment `lstlistings` or `\lstinline` are not supported. Package `filecontents` helps to put the listings into a file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{textcomp}% TS1 encoding for the degree sign
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-lst-degree}
10°C
\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting[inputencoding=utf8/latin1]{\jobname-lst-degree}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Since we are in listings, I would try to make the `°C` monospaced, wether it's two chars, or just one. I can't try righ now, but something like `literate={°}{\makebox[\widthof{i}]{\textdegree}}1` or `literate={°C}{\makebox[\widthof{M}]{\textdegree C}}1`. I used different `\widthof`s just in case we are not in a monospaced font, to get something next to the reality.

Comment: @Manuel The best approach depends on the `columns` settings (`fixed`, `flexible`, `fullflexible`). In case of `literate`, the third argument already specifies the number of character columns, here it is `1`. The symbol is small enough for one column, therefore `\makebox` trickery is not needed. And for flexible layouts, the natural width is good enough.

Comment: My error messages are in german so here is a roughly translated version of it, when I try both of your methods:
'cant't find a LaTeX method for the symbol '°' (Code-Point 0xb0)'

Comment: @Professor_Dodo The `.log` file contains the correct error message. Please use the complete error message from this file.  That makes it a lot easier for other users to help you. Maybe you have an encoding problem, the updated question uses `\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}`, but "Code-Point" comes from Unicode's terminology. If the TeX file is UTF-8 encoded, then correct the option for `inputenc` and my answer applies. Otherwise the code in the updated question runs fine encoded in `latin9`, when I add the missing `\begin{itemize}` and `10°C` inside the listings.

Answer (score 1):

We can add degree circle in lyx:

In text, with "insert" then "special character" then "symbols..." Then
"Latin-1 Supplement" and click on "degree circle", there are 2 size
degreeCircle in Latin-1 supplement category.

In formula , from "Math Panels" then click "Miscellaneous" then click
"textdegree".